# Transfer file from one host to multiple remote hosts using knife?

Tags: chef-infra, devops, remote-server, knife

Does anyone know how can we transfer file from one host to multiple remote hosts using knife?

I'm looking to find a command similar to SFTP but using knife.

Thanks!

Comment: Chef does not have functionality to transfer files directly between nodes. You can use knife to run scp commands between the nodes or you can put files on external host and use chef recipe/rsync/curl/etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is not something Chef particularly supports itself. You could write a thing, but probably just use `sftp` or `scp` yourself.